# interior points of epigraph

Tags: real-analysis, functions, convex-analysis

Consider a convex function $f$ and an interior point $x'$ of its domain.

The vector $(x',f(x'))$ does not belong to interior of the epigraph of $f$.

Why is that the case?

The epigraph is defined as follows: $\{(x,r)\in \ dom(f) \times \mathbb{R}: f(x) \leq r\}$

Comment: The points $(x', f(x')-{1 \over n})$ do not lie in the epigraph.

Comment: To which characterisation are you refering to?

Comment: So (x',f(x')) cannot be on boundary since  your point lies not in the interior simultanously?

Comment: You asked why does the point $z=(x', f(x'))$ not belong to the interior of the epigraph. The points $z_n=(x', f(x')-{1 \over n})$ do not lie in the epigraph and are arbitrarily close to $z$ hence $z$ cannot be in the epigraph interior.

Comment: I see but does it lie on the boundary then?

Comment: Well, it is in the epigraph but not in the interior, so????

Comment: Yes there is no other choice. Sorry

Comment: No problem, more importantly, there is a hyperplane passing through $(x',f(x'))$ such that the epigraph lies on one 'side' of the hyperplane (as in $\le$). This is hugely important or convex stuff. It is related to subgradients and the like.

Comment: The epigraf is the set of all points on and above the graph of f. Does  (x', f(x')) lie on the graph of f? Then we could seperate the epigraph and this vector by a plane in a weak sense?

Comment: Yes, the $(x',f(x'))$ **is** on the graph. And yes, you can separate this point weakly. May not seem like much, but it is a big deal.

Comment: Yeah then the subderivative is non empty and so on. Thanks now everything makes sense:)

Comment: Somethings look 'obvious' with convex analysis but can be rather hard to prove.